# Strings carrying Kalb-Ramond charge

Tags: string-theory

I am confused about how strings in bosonic string theory carry Kalb-Ramond ($B_{\mu\nu}$) charge.  This idea is usually introduced by analogy to how the worldline of a charged point particle couples to the EM gauge potential $A_\mu$. The string/Kalb-Ramond case is just supposed to be the two-form generalization of this. See 7.2.1 of Tong's notes.

But in the particle/EM case, the charged particles (electron/positron) can just be introduced by fiat. In string theory, the only allowed particle states are what we find from quantizing the string, namely the graviton, dilaton, and Kalb-Ramond states. None of these carry a discrete charge like an electron.

So, when people claim strings carry Kalb-Ramond charge, which string states are they talking about?

Comment: All string states carry one unit of Kalb-Ramond charge. One can see it by looking at how the various string states couples with $B_{mn}$ field. This charge is couting the number of strings. This gauge field is a 2 form field so they are integrated over 2-dimensional objects, the worldsheet. If you compactify the 9 th direction than the $B_9m$ will be a usual one form gauge field and strings with winding number along 9 will carry charge under this one form field in a conventional way.

Comment: @Nogueira, thanks for the comment.  Zweibach problem 16.3 says the Kalb Ramond charge of a closed string always vanishes.  So in a closed string theory without any compactification, what does it mean for strings to carry this charge or interact with a Kalb Ramond background in a nonlinear sigma model?  Are the closed strings KR dipoles?

Comment: I think that the intuition from point-like charges is not aplicable for higher dimension charges. At least not in the way you presented. What does generalize is the concept of flux. An object with higher dimension charge will flux a higher dimension form. In this case the correct statement is that F-strings fluxes the $H_{mnp}$ field. You can see this at the perturbative level by noting that the the gauge field $B_{mn}$ shows up in the calculation. The strings are neutral under Ramond-Ramond so only the RR field strenght, not the RR potential, show up in worldsheet computations for example.